# CSS "display:block" not working on Chrome for Android

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, mobile

I've written a new post to my blog and the page looks fine in all browsers, except **Chrome for Android 4.4.4** (KitKat). *Update: didn't work for Android Marshmallow too.*

The only different thing this particular post has is a scrollable table, styled on a custom stylesheet:

```
.article_body table {
    width: 100%;
} 
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    .article_body table {
        width: auto;
        display: block;
        overflow: auto;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        white-space: nowrap;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        clear: both;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
        touch-action: auto;
        -ms-touch-action: auto;
    }   
}
```

The table is scrollable in all browsers, except Chrome on Android. But the most important thing is that the post is showing a white block from some point on, until the end of the post, as shown on the screenshots below:

### Beginning of the error

---

[image: error beginning]

---

### End of the error:

[image: error end]

---

TESTS:

- PC, Win 7 (IE 11, Chrome, Firefox) - OK
- iPhone, iOS 9.3.1 (Chrome and Safari) - OK
- Windows Phone (IE) - OK
- Moto G - Mozilla Firefox - OK
- Moto G - Google Chrome - **failed** (portrait only)

All the other posts within my blog are ok on all these browsers.

CSS test:

After some tests I've found out the error relies on `display:block;`.

If I change or remove this property, the white block disappears on Chrome, but the layout is awful in all other browsers.

### What should I do to fix this?!

---

Blog post: http://blog.virtuacreative.com.br/upgrade-jekyll-2-to-3-gh-pages.html

Android version: `Android 4.4.4; XT1032 Build/KXB21.14-L1.40`

Chrome: `49.0.2623.105`

Comment: Wouldn't 'display: table' make more sense? Since this is a table...

Comment: Yep! Thanks @JoostS for leaving a comment, I'm really worried about this and I've got nothing so far. "Display: table" was my first thought too. But if I do so, the table doesn't scroll horizontally, it displays 100% width. It breaks the layout, we need to scroll the entire page to the right to be able to see the menu bars. Today I tested on Android Marshmallow, Chrome has the same issue as it has on KitKat. I'm pretty stuck here! This post is important and I'm avoiding sharing it while I don't manage to fix this.

Comment: What if you wrap the table in a div and you put the overflow on the div?

Comment: Thanks again @JoostS! I think I tried that too, but not sure how did I do that (I've tried a lot of different combinations). Would you mind posting a possible answer? Do you think it's possible that something else is interfering, like any other div wrapping the post content?

Comment: I created a pen to isolate the problem, but that works fine. Emulating a mobile view in desktop Chrome works fine too. However I see the problem on my mobile Chrome. I also see two js errors in the page. You should fix them before looking further.

Comment: Try removing the animation.css and other css files one by one. I suspect that will help you to find the problem. I think this is a css problem. It seems like the height of the div 'main' has a max, but I could not find that in the css.

Comment: Thanks @JoostS! Which JS errors did you find? I'm not a JS person, I basically copy and paste JS and jQuery scripts. I mean, I know how to use them, but not to debugg them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, thanks to [@JoostS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2397550/joosts) insights I managed to fix this annoying error myself with this @media query for Chrome only:

```
/* @media queries for Chrome 29+ only */

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
  and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) and (max-width: 479px) {
    .fadeIn {
        display: initial;
        margin-left: 5% !important;
    }
    article {
        padding-left: 5%;
        padding-right: 5%;
    } 
}
```

See https://gitlab.com/snippets/17238 for more Chrome media queries.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem for the white area. It lies in the animate.css Change the following line;

```
<div class="header-color col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 animated fadeIn">
```

Into this:

```
<div class="header-color col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
```

I suspect that the transition (fadein), which has a 2000px value in it, is the one causing the problem with the white space/cut off.

You can probably also multiply this value by 10 to solve this problem.

Comment: Thank you for you anwer! I'll try it tomorrow and I'll let you know how it goes. I didn't understand that part you said about multiplying by 10. How would that solve the issue?

Comment: You can use 'find and replace' on '2000px' in animate.css and replace them with '20000px'.

Comment: Thank you @JoostS, you helped me a lot! I managed to fix the issue by playing around `.fadeIn`. I posted an answer just to help others who might face similar problems. By fixing the white area, the table scrolling worked fine as well! :D Thank you very much!